# Bash script to see user exists and their status (locked or unlocked like passwd -S)

Tags: linux, bash

I'm new here.

I'm writting a script that I want to see in multiple machines if a user exists and their status. Like if I use passwd -S.

I starting writing the following bash script.  I'm stuck in this step.

**I want to show the status of the user, locked or unlocked. I can't finish with the user's status information.**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "usage: $0 <username> <serverfile>"
    exit 1
fi

USER=$1
SERVERFILE=$2


for SERVER in `cat ${SERVERFILE}`
do
        if [ -n "`ping -c1 ${SERVER} 2> /dev/null | grep icmp_seq`" ]; then
        ISUSER=`ssh -i /home/centos/key.pem user@${SERVER} getent passwd ${USER}`
        if [ $? -eq 0 ];
        then
                echo -e "User ${USER} exist on ${SERVER} [OK]"
        else
                echo  -e "User ${USER} does not exist on ${SERVER} [FAILED]"
fi
else
                echo "${SERVER} is not reachable"
fi

done
```

Could anyone have an ideia to how I can have the result like this:

**"User root exist and the status is unlocked"**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't read lines with for and don't use upper case variables, it will collide with the internal/global/environment variables... try  https://shellcheck.net

Comment: How do you know that the user is unlocked? or rather what is `unlocked` and `locked` what defines it?

Comment: The only thing "locked" I found that it refers to when a user has locked password - he can't change the password then. You can also "disable" an account (ie. set the password to empty string).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. The ***"User root exist and the status is unlocked"*** is not clear to me.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

user=$1
serverfile=$2

while read -ru "$fd" server; do
  if ping -c1 $server > /dev/null 2>&1; then
   if isuser=$(ssh "$user@$server" "getent passwd $user"); then
      printf '%b\n' "User $user exist on $server [OK]"
    else
      printf '%b\n' "User $user does not exist on $server [FAILED]"
    fi
  else
    echo "$server is not reachable"
  fi
done {fd}< "$serverfile"
```

However shell programmers often refer the term ***shell injection*** for randomly using shell vars via `ssh`

Here is an alternative/work around for that. Using `printf '%q'`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

user=$1
serverfile=$2

while read -ru "$fd" server; do
  if ping -c1 "$server" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    if printf 'getent passwd %q\n' "$user" | ssh "$user@$server" bash >/dev/null; then
      printf '%b\n' "User $user exist on $server [OK]"
    else
      printf '%b\n' "User $user does not exist on $server [FAILED]"
    fi
  else
    echo "$server is not reachable"
  fi
done {fd}< "$serverfile"
```

- It is using a random `fd` for the `while read` loop since `ssh` eats input from `stdin`, and it will only process the first line of the server file.
- Need to add more code to sanitize input.

Comment: You'll need to add your credentials using the `-i` option like in your script.

Comment: Hi @Jetchisel, I'll try this script. But, what I need is to see the status of the user like passwd -S user. I need to see if a user is locked or not. If a user is locked, I have to lock manually in each machine.

Comment: Please add that to your question/post, explain what is locked and unlocked

Comment: `'getent passwd $user'` -> `"getent passwd $user"`.

Comment: @wmvalente, You should be doing this with the tools created/written for this task, like , puppet and friends, kinda busy now so hopefully someone can chime in and help you.